# Strange words appearing during compilation of Application

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I am having a service written in C++ and i use VC++ 6.0.

When i build this service i get a strange message as shown (The letter 'T'coming during compilation). Though it does not cause any problem, i would like to know why this message occurs.

```
Compiling...
SerString.cpp
SerSwitcher.cpp
Smtp.cpp
SysConfigBlob.cpp
T
T
TransLateReportNames.cpp
```

Comment: Beside your point, I know, but I can't help but notice that you are using a twelve year old compiler which was bashed for its shortcomings regarding standard conformance the very year it was released.

Comment: I understand the frailties associated with VC 6.0 but there are other reasons why we have not yet migrated to any other compiler.

Comment: I would really like to hear what reasons that would be.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Perhaps [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_preprocessor#User-defined_compilation_errors_and_warnings) explains it?

Try to look for `#warning T` or `#pragma message ("T")` inside your code / headers.

Comment: Unfortunately i cant find this anywhere in my entire codebase

Comment: Well, it was a long shot... sorry I couldn't help.

Comment: Sure no problem just was curious to know. This has been something that bugs me everytime a new comer in the team asks what is this?